# Find importance of OSM location

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, nominatim

This is scenario: I am tourist in a new place, say city, and I want to use  smart phone to get interesting places around me. To do that I search OSM (using overpass API) for nodes and ways with tag "tourism", and query returns bunch of places. If there a way to rank them? I saw questions about "popularity rank" in OSM, and I understand it's not OSM purpose. However as a tourist I do not necessary want to go to a popular place (to spend time in line), I want to go to place with maybe nice view, a story, place related to a famous person.

I was thinking I could rank places by number of tags (the more tags, the more info, more likely there is something interesting there), by number of edits, by number of nodes in OSM way (if somebody spent time entering all tags and defining way, maybe it's worth visiting), by presence of tag with URL. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please remember to take the new user [tour] which states there should be only one question per question.  Asking multiple questions makes this too broad.  Additionally, asking for "any other ideas" will also make this too broad.

Comment: The corresponding Wikipedia page yields a pretty good indication about the importance of this place. That's why Nominatim uses this as a source to calculate the place rank, among OSM tags such as `place` and `admin_level`.

Comment: Thank you, @scai! I read about Nominatim and wikipedia, I did not know it uses tags too. Nominatim was in my question, but I was asked to to be more specific and avoid multiple questions:) So in this more limited scope my question is: are OSM only data sufficient to make guesses about "importance", and which tags would be good indicators. I will look more into what Nominatim does with tags. Than you for the info!

Comment: The previously mentioned tags place and admin_level are only interesting for cities and similar places. For tourism attractions this is *a lot* harder. Often OSM data is not enough to calculate the importance. Imagine you have two museums or two castles in your surrounding. Which one is the more important one? The Wikipedia article will give a good indication here. For offline purposes consider either downloading such Wikipedia data beforehand or taking a look at the surroundings. E.g. how far is the nearest bus stop and how many parking spaces are available? Not very good indicators, though.